# Corrupt MXD Causes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mxd, corrupt

What would be a few common events that could cause an .mxd to become corrupt? I have a few docs that eventually crash on me and the best solution is to continuously use the MXD doctor to fix the MXD.

Comment: Are you storing the file locally, or on a network?  What kind of network?  On what operating system?

Comment: I usually keep the document local. There are times where it may be sent zipped on an FTP site or email.

Comment: I've found "doing anything in ArcMap" can be enough to result in an eventually corrupted map. I'm interested to know about other possible causes, though, maybe I'm incorrectly assigning the blame :)

Comment: Back in the days of 8 & 9x, I found that making the template (normal.mxt) read only (except when customizing it of course) helped with individual project corruption. But in all versions I've found that frequently used projects can sometimes just develop quirks and there is nothing I can do about it but create a new one.  You could try saving your project with another name or to another location which will compact the mxd.  Mxd doctor has never worked well for me in the long run.

Comment: I've closed this as "too broad" because it is asking an open-ended question.  To be on-topic I think you need to asking specifically about your hypothesis about what might be making your MXD corrupt rather than seeking a list of what might be making it corrupt based on others' experiences (which could be totally unrelated).