# ArcGIS corrupting MXD-files on certain users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, mxd, corrupt

In our organisation we have a number of ArcGIS users whose ArcGIS desktop installations cause MXD-files to go corrupt when they are saved.

All MXD files that are saved with ArcGIS Desktop by one of these windows users become corrupt and unreadable. It doesn't matter if it's a fresh empty map, or an older document containing data.

We have tried deleting the "Normal.mxt" template files in AppData to force a settings reset, but that has not helped.

The problem is bound to the windows login rather than the computer, and it concerns both fresh installs and older installs. The version is 10.3.1

My hypothesis is that ArcGIS corrupts even the supposedly fresh "Normal.mxt" template files when they are reset.

So, are there other places that ArcGIS stores settings information except for the "Normal.mxt" files in AppData?

If you have another experience or theory for the MXD-corruption, please share that as well.

*(I read through [Corrupt MXD Causes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137943) which was closed, and I understand if this one is a bit too vague as well, although I've tried to narrow it down some.)*

Comment: What type of layers do they have in the MXD when it's saved?

Comment: What if you copy the Normal.mxt from a user that doesn't get corrupt files to one that does? And the other way around?

Comment: I think this is an issue that you should consult with Esri's technical support about because, unless you can describe a series of steps that other users can follow to reproduce the corruption you are describing, it must be classed as non-reproducible here. Remember that [**We are not a GIS Software Support Site**. We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @PolyGeo Fair enough. I guess I tend to have better luck here than with support though. I'll try what Martin said in any case.

Comment: My experience is that not all Esri distributors support their technical support teams well, but if you can get examples of your corrupt MXDs through them to Redlands, then they have much more sophisticated diagnostic tools available.  If you can strike a reproducible procedure then by all means edit this question and I'll be happy to re-open it.